# How does one isolate an input from another input in the same call to shiny::renderUI?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a number of inputs that all exist in the same `conditionalPanel` that is created on the server side of things using `renderUI`. I cannot move this to the user interface, because some parts use reactive objects.

What I am trying to do is have one input determine what the default for another input should be. However, since both of these exist in the same call to `renderUI`, it creates a circular dependency, which keeps me from selecting anything but the default option for the former input. Consider this example `app.R` file:

```
library(shiny)

key <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3, "d" = 4)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("inputs")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$inputs <- renderUI(
    tagList(
      selectInput("input1", "Input 1:", letters[1:4]),
      textInput("input2", "Input 2:", rval())
    )
  )

  rval <- reactive(key[input$input1])

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I define the `key` in the global environment (in the app, this is read from a .yaml file in the global), then the `uiOutput` shows the user all of the inputs. We can see that the default for `input2` relies on what one selects for `input1`. What happens is `input1` triggers a change in `rval()`, which in turn triggers a change in `input2`. This is OK. However, because `input1` and `input2` are rendered in the same call to `renderUI`, then `input1` becomes dependent on itself, thus resetting to the default whenever the user selects another option in the dropdown.

Again, I am coding it like this because the two inputs exist in the same `conditionalPanel` in the actual app I am working with (although it is not in this working example).

I tried surrounding `selectInput(...)` with `isolate()`, but this does not work.

How can I keep the two inputs in the same `renderUI` but allow the user to change `input1` without it being dependent on itself and resetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `observeEvent(iunputs$input1, ...)` and `updateTextinput` to keep `input2` up-to-date. Using this approach has the advantage that your UI doesn't have to be re-rendered as often.

```
library(shiny)

key <- c("a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3, "d" = 4)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("inputs")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$inputs <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("input1", "Input 1:", letters[1:4]),
      textInput("input2", "Input 2:", "placeholder")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$input1, {
    mapped_input <- key[[req(input$input1)]]
    updateTextInput(session, "input2", value = mapped_input)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`req` makes sure `updateTextInput` will only be called if `output$inputs` is already rendered.

I realize that there are usecases where the `updateXXX` functions are not enough to render dynamic inputs. In this case, it is probably best to generate the UIs in seperate `renderUI` statements so circularity is no longer an issue.

Note: I don't see how `conditionalPanel` makes it necessary to use `renderUI`. If you are looking for ways to use abstraction in your code, use [Shiny Modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if I was unclear—I have things that can only be done in a reactive environment in the condintionalPanel, meaning I needed to put everything in the sever and use renderUI so that I could use reactivity in them. (I was able to maneuver things into different calls to `renderUI` after sleeping on it.) What about updateXXX makes it "client-side"?

Comment: Ah, I see. I was just assuming `renderUI` might have been used for abstraction because I have seen this in some `shiny` apps in the past. Client-side was certainly a misleading choice of words from me and I just edited that part out. What I meant to say by that is that the input widgets get updated by id like they would be in a usual JavaScript setup.